# Adding Unique columns along with the filters in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply filters in columns as well as select unique values of unrelated columns using pandas.

I want to get all the data which is based on filters applied on ColumnOne and ColumnTwo based on unique values in ColumnThree.

```
df.loc[(df['ColumnOne']==1) & (df['ColumnTwo']=='NW') & (df['ColumnThree'].unique())]
```

I want the values of all the data displayed according to filters and unique values.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as you want : `df[(df['ColumnOne']==1) & df['ColumnTwo']=='NW')].drop_duplicates(subset=['ColumnThree'], keep=first)`

You can change the `keep` argument as follow:

- first : Drop duplicates except for the first occurrence.
- last : Drop duplicates except for the last occurrence.
- False : Drop all duplicates.

Documentation : [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for insight.
The code worked with the changes mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code worked with the following changes :

> > > newVariable = df[(df['ColumnOne']==1) & (df['ColumnTwo']=='NW')]
> > >       newVariable.drop_duplicates(subset=['ColumnThree'])